# Is there any way in Oracle support this requirement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
-----------
UID | NAME
-----------
1   | 'AAA'
1   | 'BBB'
2   | 'AAA'
3   | 'BBB'
3   | 'CCC'
3   | 'DDD'
```

I want to write a query to show the result like this:

```
-----------
UID | NAME
-----------
1   | 'AAA','BBB'
2   | 'AAA'
3   | 'BBB','CCC','DDD'
```

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: _Is it possible to do that ?_ offcourse what did u TRY?

Answer (score 0):

[oracle11g](/questions/tagged/oracle11g) and above offer the [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) function:

```
SELECT   uid, LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY uid
```